# Recipe to copy 1D strided data with cudaMemcpy2D

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, cuda, stride

If one has two continuous ranges of device memory it is possible to copy memory from from one to the other using `cudaMemcpy`.

```
   double* source = ...
   double* dest = ...
   cudaMemcpy(dest, source, N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Now suppose that I want to copy source into dest, but every 2 or 3 elements respectively. 
That is `dest[0] = source[0], dest[3] = source[2], dest[6] = source[4], ...`.
Of course a single plain `cudaMemcpy` cannot do this.

Intuitively, `cudaMemcpy2D` should be able to do the job, because "strided elements can be see as a column in a larger array".
But `cudaMemcpy2D` it has many input parameters that are obscure to interpret in this context, such as `pitch`.

For example, I manager to use `cudaMemcpy2D` to reproduce the case where both strides are 1.

```
    cudaMemcpy2D(dest, 1, source, 1, 1, n*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

But I cannot figure out the general case, with `dest_stride` and `source_stride` difference from 1.

**Is there a way to copy strided data to stride data with `cudaMemcpy2D`?**
In which order do I have to put the known information about the layout?, namely, in terms of the two strides and `sizeof(T)`.

```
    cudaMemcpy2D(dest, ??, source, ???, ????, ????, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic function for such a strided copy could look roughly like this:

```
void cudaMemcpyStrided(
        void *dst, int dstStride, 
        void *src, int srcStride, 
        int numElements, int elementSize, int kind) {
    int srcPitchInBytes = srcStride * elementSize;
    int dstPitchInBytes = dstStride * elementSize;
    int width = 1 * elementSize;
    int height = numElements;
    cudaMemcpy2D(
        dst, dstPitchInBytes, 
        src, srcPitchInBytes, 
        width, height,
        kind);
}
```

And for your example, it could be called as

```
cudaMemcpyStrided(dest, 3, source, 2, 3, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

---

"Roughly", because I just translated it on the fly from the (Java/JCuda based) code that I tested it with:

```
import static jcuda.runtime.JCuda.cudaMemcpy2D;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

import jcuda.Pointer;
import jcuda.Sizeof;
import jcuda.runtime.cudaMemcpyKind;

public class JCudaStridedMemcopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dstLength = 9;
        int srcLength = 6;
        int dstStride = 3;
        int srcStride = 2;
        int numElements = 3;
        runExample(dstLength, dstStride, srcLength, srcStride, numElements);

        dstLength = 9;
        srcLength = 12;
        dstStride = 3;
        srcStride = 4;
        numElements = 3;
        runExample(dstLength, dstStride, srcLength, srcStride, numElements);

        dstLength = 18;
        srcLength = 12;
        dstStride = 3;
        srcStride = 2;
        numElements = 6;
        runExample(dstLength, dstStride, srcLength, srcStride, numElements);

    }

    private static void runExample(int dstLength, int dstStride, int srcLength, int srcStride, int numElements) {
        double dst[] = new double[dstLength];
        double src[] = new double[srcLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            src[i] = i;
        }

        cudaMemcpyStrided(dst, dstStride, src, srcStride, numElements);

        System.out.println("Copy " + numElements + " elements");
        System.out.println("  to   array with length " + dstLength + ", with a stride of " + dstStride);
        System.out.println("  from array with length " + srcLength + ", with a stride of " + srcStride);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Destination:");
        System.out.println(toString2D(dst, dstStride));
        System.out.println("Flat: " + Arrays.toString(dst));

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Source:");
        System.out.println(toString2D(src, srcStride));
        System.out.println("Flat: " + Arrays.toString(src));

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Done");
        System.out.println("");

    }

    private static void cudaMemcpyStrided(double dst[], int dstStride, double src[], int srcStride, int numElements) {
        long srcPitchInBytes = srcStride * Sizeof.DOUBLE;
        long dstPitchInBytes = dstStride * Sizeof.DOUBLE;
        long width = 1 * Sizeof.DOUBLE;
        long height = numElements;
        cudaMemcpy2D(
                Pointer.to(dst), dstPitchInBytes, 
                Pointer.to(src), srcPitchInBytes, 
                width, height,
                cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyHostToHost);
    }

    public static String toString2D(double[] a, long columns) {
        String format = "%4.1f ";
        ;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i % columns == 0) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            sb.append(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, format, a[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

To give an idea of what the function does, based on the examples/test cases, here is the output:

```
Copy 3 elements
  to   array with length 9, with a stride of 3
  from array with length 6, with a stride of 2

Destination:
 0.0  0.0  0.0 
 2.0  0.0  0.0 
 4.0  0.0  0.0 
Flat: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Source:
 0.0  1.0 
 2.0  3.0 
 4.0  5.0 
Flat: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

Done

Copy 3 elements
  to   array with length 9, with a stride of 3
  from array with length 12, with a stride of 4

Destination:
 0.0  0.0  0.0 
 4.0  0.0  0.0 
 8.0  0.0  0.0 
Flat: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Source:
 0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0 
 4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0 
 8.0  9.0 10.0 11.0 
Flat: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]

Done

Copy 6 elements
  to   array with length 18, with a stride of 3
  from array with length 12, with a stride of 2

Destination:
 0.0  0.0  0.0 
 2.0  0.0  0.0 
 4.0  0.0  0.0 
 6.0  0.0  0.0 
 8.0  0.0  0.0 
10.0  0.0  0.0 
Flat: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Source:
 0.0  1.0 
 2.0  3.0 
 4.0  5.0 
 6.0  7.0 
 8.0  9.0 
10.0 11.0 
Flat: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]

Done
```

Comment: I guess the downvote is due to the fact that there' some Java code in there? Consider it as an add-on. The relevant function is in C, for that matter.

Comment: It is a pitty that `cudaMemcpy2D` doesn't accept 0 (zero) as the `srcPitchInBytes` argument (returns error), that would allow for a more sane `memset` function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done. It is easier to illustrate in code than words so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t swidth = 2;
    const size_t sheight = 4;
    size_t spitch = swidth * sizeof(int);
    int source[swidth * sheight] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; 


    const size_t dwidth = 3;
    const size_t dheight = 4;
    size_t dpitch = dwidth * sizeof(int);
    int dest[dwidth * dheight] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };

    const size_t cwidth = 1 * sizeof(int);
    const size_t cheight = 3;

    int* source_d; cudaMalloc(&source_d, spitch * sheight);
    cudaMemcpy(source_d, &source[0], spitch * sheight, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy2D(&dest[0], dpitch, source_d, spitch, cwidth, cheight, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i < 12; i++) std::cout << i << " " << dest[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which does this:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o strided_copy strided_copy.cu 
$ cuda-memcheck ./strided_copy
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0 0
1 -1
2 -1
3 2
4 -1
5 -1
6 4
7 -1
8 -1
9 -1
10 -1
11 -1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

In essence, you are copying a width of 4 bytes (an int) with a stride of 8 bytes (two ints) into a destination with a stride of 12 bytes (three ints). I only copied three rwos so that it obvious how the row argument works. Adjust the size of the copy element and strides, etc. to taste.