# How to asynchronously copy a disjoint subset of an array from device to host with CUDA/Thrust?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm not sure if this is possible or not in an asynchronous fashion, but what I'd like to do is the following. Suppose I have the following array on device:

`d_arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Also suppose I have a host array `h_arr` of size `3`. Lastly, suppose I have the following array of pointers:

`p_arr = [&d_arr[0], &d_arr[4], &d_arr[8]]`

I would like to call an imaginary function

`cudaMemcpyAsyncDisjoint(&d_arr[0], &h_arr[0], &p_arr[0], 3)`

Which then fills the array `h_arr` such that it becomes

`h_arr = [0, 4, 8]`

I want to do this asynchronously because my main concern is speed, since I have a driver method which runs kernels in a loop and then copies back data at the end of each round.

Comment: `thrust::gather` already does this

Comment: This kind of operation is generally called a gather (Thrust, MPI, etc). Normally you want to gather into another segment of device memory first and then copy that back to the host, as the transfer to the host is expensive. I'm not sure what Thust does, when you put a host vector and a device vector into the gather algorithm by default. If that works at all, you might want to specify the execution policy explicitly for clarity where the actual gather happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the strides between elements of `p_arr` are constant, then this is possible in [a single operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597299/recipe-to-copy-1d-strided-data-with-cudamemcpy2d) with `cudaMemcpy2DAsync`.

For varying strides its *not possible* in a single operation.  Furthermore, the single operation method (with constant stride) is  not necessarily the fastest way (the `cudaMemcpy2DAsync` method does not necessarily get close to expected bus transfer speeds).  For the fastest method, plus ability to handle varying strides between elements to be copied, the usual recommendation is to to break this into two steps.

1. Do something like `thrust::gather` (or `thrust::copy` with a permutation iterator) to collect all elements to be copied into a contiguous, temporary device buffer
2. then use `cudaMemcpyAsync` to copy that buffer to host.